# Only one chart to parameterize a unit-cylinder

Tags: differential-geometry

I want to parameterize a unit-cylinder $x^2+y^2=1$ with only **one chart** in a complete atlas (the sets must be open). The cylinder is in $\mathbb{R}^3$. One way to do the parametrization with two charts is:
$$ \textbf{x}(u,v)=(\cos u, \sin u, v)$$
with $v\in \mathbb{R}$ and $0<u< 2\pi$ (this is the *open set* $U_1=(0,2\pi)\times \mathbb{R}$) and
$$ \textbf{y}(\overline{u}, \overline{v}) = (\cos \overline{u}, \sin \overline{u}, \overline{v})$$
with $\overline{v}\equiv v\in \mathbb{R}$ and $-\pi < \overline{u} < \pi$ (this is the *open set* $U_2 = (-\pi,\pi)\times\mathbb{R}$). So the **atlas** is $\{ \textbf{x}, \textbf{y}\}$ into $U_1 \times U_2.$ So, it has two charts $\textbf{x}$ and $\textbf{y}$ defined in *open sets* (this is important: the set $(0,2 \pi]\times \mathbb{R}$ is **not open**, and a parametrization has to be defined into an open set).

Do someone know an atlas with only one chart? For example, with a reparametrization. The only thing I know is that the atlas with one chart exists in this case$^*$.

*[Introduction to Topological Quantum Matter & Quantum Computation, Tudor D. Stanescu](https://books.google.es/books?id=-88BDgAAQBAJ&pg=PT79&lpg=PT79&dq=%22the+cylinder+can+be+constructed+using+one+chart%22&source=bl&ots=tP6zF1V8YS&sig=COQKz2XG2xDGw8OBpVK0z1hqn98&hl=es&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjKqp3f5sLSAhXMDxoKHTefDe8Q6AEIIjAA#v=onepage&q=%22the%20cylinder%20can%20be%20constructed%20using%20one%20chart%22&f=false)

PD: Something similar in General Relativistic to changing Schwarzchild coordinates by Kruskal–Szekeres ones to extend the well-behaved domain.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the chart
$$ \mathbf x(u,v) = \left(\frac{u}{\sqrt{u^2+v^2}}, \frac{v}{\sqrt{u^2+v^2}}, \log \sqrt{u^2+v^2} \right)\,,$$
defined on $\mathbf R^2 \setminus \{(0,0)\}$. The formula is simpler in polar coordinates,
$$ \mathbf x(r,\theta) = \left( \cos \theta, \sin \theta, \log r\right)\,. $$

Comment: Isn't the polar coordinate map just $\mathbf{x}(r, \theta) = (\cos \theta, \sin \theta, \log r)$?

Comment: Yes, of course it is. Thanks for spotting it.

Comment: Where is $\theta$ defined?

Comment: On the same domain as the variable $u$ in the OP. It just makes the formula prettier, but to get the global chart you need to use the first formula.

Comment: If we denote $z =u + \text{i}v=r \text{e}^{\text{i}\theta}$, then why the domain of the chart changes from an open set to a non-open set in order to describe the same surface $S^1 \times \mathbb{R}$? I.e. from $z\in \mathbb{C}-\{0\}$ or $(u,v) \in \mathbb{R}^2-\{(0,0)\}$ (open set) to $(r,\theta) \in \mathbb{R}_+ \times [0,2\pi)$ (non-open set).