# Different domain of a same image function $f: \mathbb{R}^2 \longrightarrow \mathbb{C}$.

Tags: complex-analysis, multivariable-calculus, differential-geometry

Suppose a function $f: \mathbb{R}^2 \longrightarrow \mathbb{C}$ defined by
$$ f(x,y)=x+iy. \tag{1}$$
In this case the domain of $f$ is both **open** (and closed). Now we reparameterize the function and we change the domain of the function in orden to get the same image $\mathbb{C}$: $g: [0,\infty) \times [0,2\pi) \longrightarrow \mathbb{C}$ defined by
$$ g(r,\theta) = r \text{e}^{\text{i}\theta}. \tag{2}$$
Now, the domain of $g$ is **not open**. Note that $f(x,y)=g(r,\theta)=g\bigl(\phi(x,y)\bigr)$ is the definition of a *scalar* being
$$ \phi(x,y) \equiv \bigl( \phi_1(x,y), \phi_2(x,y)\bigr) = \bigl(\sqrt{x^2+y^2}, \arctan \dfrac{y}{x}\bigr).$$

I'm interested in **open sets** because of the parametrization of the unit-cylinder with only one chart as we can see in this question:
[Only one chart to parameterize a unit-cylinder](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2178416/only-one-chart-to-parameterize-a-unit-cylinder/2178423#2178423).

> My question is: Why the domain of the function that I've used to parameterize the unit-cylinder changes to *not-open set* and then, I cannot use it for parameterizing?

Comment: I'm not sure that the first part of the question really makes sense. You have two maps that happen to have the same image. For one the domain is open relative to a certain set, for the other that's not true.

Comment: I don't think that **the domain of g is not open**.

Comment: And if the domain of $g$ is open, why $\textbf{r}(u,v)=(\cos u, \sin u, v)$ isn't cover $S^1 \times \mathbb{R}$? I mean what's the problem in $u=0,2\pi$?

Answer (score 2):

Part of this has to do with the fact that the $g$ is not bijective and $\phi$ is not actually the inverse of $g$.  In fact, $\phi$ is only defined when $x \neq 0$.